# Copy specified child node from one xml file to another xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

Below are my two xml files-
**Sample xml file**

```html
<tbltemp>
   <Details>  
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>09:30:45</Time>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
 </Details>
 <Details>
   <Id>2</Id>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>01:30:45</Time>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
 </Details>
 <Details>
   <Id>3</Id>
   <Name>John</Name>
   <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>11:36:45</Time>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
   </Details>
 <Details>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>Jack</Name>
   <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>11:36:45</Time>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
 </Details>
</tbltemp>
```

**DBfile.xml**

```html
<tbltemp>
  <Data>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
    </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Age>24</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
</tbltemp>
```

I want to copy Date and time in DBfile.xml file from sample xml file where Ids match for both the xml file.

I want the DBfile.xml like this-

```html
<tbltemp>
  <Data>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>09:30:45</Time>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>01:30:45</Time>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
    </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>23</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>11:36:45</Time>
    <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Age>24</Age>
    <Team>Software</Team>
    <Date>25.09.2016</Date>
   <Time>11:36:45</Time>
   <Flag>1</Flag>
  </Data>
</tbltemp>
```

I have been using code like this

```
  strDetails = "sample.xml";
   strDBDir = "DBfile.xml";
 var xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(strDetails);
    var xDoc2 = XDocument.Load(strDBDir);

    var doc1Entries = xDoc1.Descendants("Details");

/// var cloneEntries = doc1Entries.Select(x => new XElement(x));//"AgentId").Value == AgentId.ToString()
                         var cloneEntries = doc1Entries.Select(x => new XElement(x));
                         xDoc2.Descendants("Date").Last().AddFirst(cloneEntries);
                         xDoc2.Descendants("Time").Last().AddAfterSelf(cloneEntries);

                         xDoc2.Save(strDBDir);
```

But unable to copy data from one file to other.,Instead it is just adding loginid into DBfile.xml

Can anyone guide here please.

Answer (score 0):

Using linq join

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument sampleDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\sample.xml");
            XDocument dbDoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\dbfile.xml");

            var merge =
                  (from db in dbDoc.Descendants("Data")
                   join sample in sampleDoc.Descendants("Details") on new { id = (int)db.Element("Id"), name = (string)db.Element("Name") } equals new { id = (int)sample.Element("Id"), name = (string)sample.Element("Name") }
                   select new { db = db, sample = sample });

            foreach (var row in merge)
            {
                row.db.Add(new object[] {
                    row.sample.Element("Date"),
                    row.sample.Element("Time")
                });
            }

        }
    }
}
```